# Duplicate detection RSS title - MYSQL & PHP

Tags: php, sql, string, mysqli, rss

I would like to know if there is a possibility to check in SQL via PHP, if there is a title that contains more than 3 letters identical from a news headline.

the website receives headlines from the world's leading news sites via RSS. And I want to filter out that there will be a difference of several hours / day a similar title (containing 3 letters or more).

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

$value = 'ABC ACB JAJAM HGOGLA';
if(dubtitle($value) === true) exit;   // dubtitle($value) = true

function dubtitle($value){

    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
    //Output any connection error
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    $start = strtotime("-1 DAY");  
    $end = time(); 

    $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, title, time FROM table WHERE (time BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$end."')");
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    $results->bind_result($id, $title, $time);

    $found = false;
    while($results->fetch()){
        $parts = explode(" ", $title); // $title = 'ABC ACB ABGF JAJA';   
        foreach ($parts as $part){ 
            if(mb_strpos(trim($part), trim($value)) !== false){
                $count++;  
            }
            if($count >= 3){
                $found = 'yes';
                break;
            }    
        }    
    }

    if($found === 'yes'){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

in my exmaple  $value = 'ABC ACB JAJA HGOGLA' / $title = 'ABC ACB ABGF JAJAm' 
we can find 3 words of $value in $title (ABC , ACB , JAJA) so the function will return true.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: So i see some code, but I do not see anything telling us what is wrong with that code?

Comment: something with "if(mb_strpos(trim($part), trim($value)) !== false){" not working.